# Standard way to handle the encapsulated access to values stored in private map without breaking the abstraction in C++

Tags: c++, containers, return-value, encapsulation

I want to create a class in order to manage markup language (such as HTML) in C++. I would like my class to retain attributes and sub-tags. The problem is, given encapsulated containers, how to properly abstract the accesses and what to return in order to provide an easy way to check if the value returned is valid.

I defined my class containing two maps as private members (nominally, `std::map<std::string, Tag> _children;` and `std::map<std::string, std::string> _attr;`. I defined two functions to populate these fields and I would like to define two functions to read-access the stored elements.

The problem is, I don't want to break my abstraction and, as I'm doing this in order to work on my c++ skills, I would like to find the proper way (or cleaner way, or standard way) to do it.

One basic solution would be to simply call `return map.find(s);`, but then I would have to define the return type of my function as `std::map<std::string, Tag>::const_iterator`, which would break the abstraction. So I could dereference the iterator returned by `map.find()`, but in case the value in not in the map I would dereference a non-dereferencable iterator (`_children.cend()`).

What I defined so far:

```
using namespace std;
class Tag {
    static const regex re_get_name, re_get_attributes;
    string _name;
    map<string,string> _attr;
    map<string,Tag> _children;
    public:
        Tag(const string &toParse) {
            /* Parse line using the regex */
        }
        const string& name() const {
            return _name;
        }
        Tag& add_child(const Tag& child) {
            _children.insert(child._name, child);
            return *this;
        }
        SOMETHING get_child(const string& name) const {
            map<string,Tag>::const_iterator val = _children.find(name);
            /* Do something here, but what ? */
            return something;
        }
        SOMETHING attr(const string& name) const {
            map<string, string>::const_iterator val = _attr.find(name);
            /* Do something here, but what ? */
            return something;
        }
};

const regex Tag::re_get_name("^<([^\\s]+)");
const regex Tag::re_get_attributes(" ([^\\s]+) = \"([^\\s]+)\"");
```

What would be the proper way to handle this kind on situation in C++? Should I create my own `Tag::const_iterator` type? If so, how to? Should I go for a more "C" approach, where I just define the return type as `Tag&` and return `NULL` if the map doesn't contain my key? Should I be more OOP with a static member `static const Tag NOT_FOUND`, and return a reference to this object if the element isn't in my map? I also thought of throwing an exception, but exception management seems to be quite heavy and ineffective in C++.

Comment: Look at `std::option`.

Comment: maybe I misunderstand the question, but why dont you simply return the `map<string,string>::const_iterator` ? It is a `const` iterator, so no encapsulation broken

Comment: @molbdnilo `std::optional` i guess

Comment: @user463035818 in this case it is the abstraction that is broken. If I want to change the implementation and not use a map anymore, then the return type will change. @user463035818 What would be the returned type ? `optional<const Tag &>` ? I suppose it would be the same for the variable that would receive the returned value for `Tag::get_child`.

Comment: you could provide a `iterator` typedef and use iterators of that type, if users use the alias their code will not break when you change the map to something else. well, not sure, i have to admit I never got what encapsulation really is about

Comment: consider eg `std::vector<T>`. You dont really care what `std::vector<T>::iterator` actually is. You just use it and if the actual type would change you wouldnt notice as long as you only refer to it via `std::vector<T>::iterator`

Comment: There are many ways to handle this, but first thing first. What kind of key are you using for the `_children` map? In DOM, children of a node do not belong in a map.

Comment: I hash on the tag's name - I want to be able to find directly the node, I don't care about their order. But here, the question I have is more abstracted to how to properly return the value stored in a private container in C++. - @user463035818 I agree it's not that the code would necessarily break, but for a design point of view, It's not too clean. In a more general manner, I wish my class to abstract the way I store information; potentially I should be able to provide a totally different class with the same name and public interface, it should be working.

Comment: maybe there is some misunderstanding (probably me ;), so I just repeat in different words: `std::vector<T>` does expose its iterator type via the `std::vector<T>::iterator` alias, when you write code using vector iterators you are using the concrete type, but if the implementation changes the type (it can be simply `T*` but it could be something else) then you dont have to change anything on your code even though the type you are using in your code changed

Comment: Ths issue I have with that is that I don't necessarily want a `std::vector<T>::iterator`, nor a `std::map<string,T>::iterator`. I don't want to see exposed outside of the class the internal storage of data. Yet, I want to have access to certain of the iterator mechanisms, such as checking if the value referenced is valid, and an effective and easy access to the value (dereferencing, or dedicated field). And I wanted to know the c++-best-practice way to do so in the case of containers as private member.

Comment: "I hash on the tag's name". In HTML tag names are not unique, and the order is significant. If your language resembles HTML, a map is not appropriate here.

Comment: If you want to return a copy of your attribute or a child, use std::optiional as the accepted answer suggests, but be aware that it entails making a copy of a potentially large and complex object. Your `Tag` is an entire tree of tags so be cautious copying this thing.

Comment: Potentially, for the exercise given, I could break the language representation and merge tags sharing the same name if they share their parent tag. As for the `std::optional`, I will probably try to use it with a reference to my stored object. It seems to be the cleanest solution, and keeps the abstraction.

Comment: "I could break the language representation and merge tags sharing the same name if they share their parent tag" You can do this if your language admits this, HTML doesn't, so I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do here. "I will probably try to use it with a reference to my stored object." std::optional that wraps a reference? Congratulations, you have just reinvented the plain old pointer, but with all the simplicity of C++17 template metaprogramming.

Comment: Hint: if you want to answer to someone's specific comment, use their user name after a @ like this: @Clément

Comment: @n.m. I'm solving an exercise where I am expected to be able to return the value of nodes attributes, described as `tag1.tag2~attr1`, `.` describing the hierarchy between tags, and `~` marking the attribute to find. So I'm fine merging attributes as there are no descriptor such as "choose second tag with name being `tag2`". As for reinventing the plain old pointer, yes and no. I'm reinventing the usage of `NULL` as an invalid pointer. But this time, I encapsulate it in a clean, standard defined, OO way. It doesn't rely on the way pointers/memory are managed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187065/discussion-between-n-m-and-clement).

Comment: Don't use optional<T&>, it would indeed be the worst of both worlds. Of you need references your design is flawed. Then you should use the containers directly and consider my recommendations below my code. 
This would also help in the problem @n.m. correctly mentioned: The order of html tags is significant, so you would let them stay in a vector or deque . Orient on DOM classes in other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::optional` could help you, but needs a C++17 ready standard library, so in the meantime you could also use `boost::optional` which is more or less the same, since AFAIK `std::optional`s design was based on the boost one. (As boost is often the source for new C++ standard proposals)

Even as I am reluctant to make you a proposal because of the general problem of your approach, I still wrote one for you, but please consider the points after the code:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <map>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

class Tag {
    static const std::regex re_get_name, re_get_attributes;
    using string = std::string;
    string _name;
    std::map<string,string> _attr;
    std::map<string,Tag> _children;
    public:
        Tag(const string &toParse) {
            /* Parse line using the regex */
        }
        const string& name() const {
            return _name;
        }
        Tag& add_child(const Tag& child) {
            _children.emplace(child._name, child);
            return *this;
        }
        boost::optional<Tag> get_child(const string& name) const {
            auto val = _children.find(name);

            return val == _children.cend() ? boost::optional<Tag>{} : boost::optional<Tag>{val->second};
        }
        boost::optional<string> attr(const string& name) const {
            auto val = _attr.find(name);

            return val == _attr.cend() ? boost::optional<string>{} : boost::optional<string>{val->second};
        }
};
```

As you can see you are basically just reimplementing container semantics of `std::map` but also with the somehow built in parser logic. I strongly disagree from this approach, since parsing gets ugly very fast in a hurry, and mixing value generation code into a container which could i.e. should be use as a value class will make things even worse.

My first suggestion is to just declare/use your `Tag` class/struct as a value class, so just containing the std::maps as public members. Put your parsing functions in a namespace along with the Tag container, and let them just be functions or distinct classes if needed.

My second suggestion is small one: Don't prefix with `_`, it's reserved and considered bad style, but you can use it as a suffix. Also don't use using namespace directives outside of a class/function/namespace block i.e. global, it's bad style in a .cpp, and extremely bad style in a header /.h/.hpp

My third suggestion: Use the boost spirit qi parser frame work, you would just declare your value classes as I suggestion first, while qi would automatically fill them, via boost fusion. If you know the EBNF notation already, you can just write the EBNF like grammar in C++, and the compiler will generate a parser via template magic. However qi and especially fusion has some issues, but it makes things much easier in the long run. Regexes only does half of the parsing logic, at best.

Comment: Itetators are fancy pointers. OP cannot return a fancy pointer, but what''s wrong with a good old plain ponter? Why change the semantics and return a copy when the original intent is to return a (possibly fancy) pointer?

Comment: @n.m. No they aren't, they are there for iterating over elements, which for random access containers like `std::vector` or `std::array` would be pointers indeed, but they aren't for associative containers like `std::map` or others, since they have to traverse the tree of the map or the buckets of other containers. Pointers can't do that.

Comment: Of course they are. They are devices for indirection, just like pointers (one can dereference them) as well as devices for iteration (just like pointers again). The original intent is to return an indirection device, not a copy.

Comment: Also using pointers for `There could be a value or a non valid value aka null aka nil` is bad style since the 90s. Pointers can do many things from doing this nullable value thing, to manage lifetime issues, to polymorphic stuff. But they are very error prone and inefficient compared to optional for nullable, shared/unique_ptr for lifetime and polymorphic, or variant or references for only polymorphic stuff.

Comment: "using pointers for ... is bad style". Iterators do it all the time and nobody cares.

Comment: @n.m. No they aren't. Almost 90% of C++ are devices for indirection, so your statement isn't very helpful since extremely generalised, yet correct. Or to quote David Wheeler: "All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection" ...except for the problem of too many layers of indirection

Comment: Of course they do, what with returning container.end() when an element is not found? All ofthe standard library is doing this.

Comment: What are you suggesting now, I'm confused, I thought you suggested to use raw pointers. Reasons to not do this see above. Now it seems you meant to return iterators. Even worse idea, since his containers are private, so how should the api user, get the end iterator to test for equality in the first place? Besides the whole lifetime issues, you got them, as for raw pointers.

IMHO just bad advice. If you want to use C or reason over turing machines keep it to yourself.

Comment: "bad style since the 90s" ? did I miss the point where returning an end iterator (which most of the time is just a pointer) to indicate a non-existing value got deprecated? I am using it almost every day

Comment: I don't know how to measure percentage of C++ which is occupied by indirection devices. Do you? Please share your methodology. Indirection is an important thing, and *if* OP needs it, your proposal doesn't answer the question as it simply removes this functionality.

Comment: OP doesn't need it. If you think otherwise create your own answer. Where, if you stick to your comments, would have to expose more of the private members to get the end iterator. Which wasn't the question.  But I guess you do not care about the question after all, just want to troll me. BB

Comment: Pointers are sometimes iterators. Not in this case however. I did not propose to return an iterator. I proposed to return a plain old pointer. It leaves the indirection ability in place (like an iterator and a reference), and it leaves the ability to indicate that the value is absent in place (like an iterator but unlike a reference), and it removes the iteration ability (unlike an iterator but like a reference), and it provides encapsulation (unlike an std::map iterator but like a reference).

Comment: OP is at some kind of learning stage so what they need may or may or not be identical to what they think they need. Are you sure they need to copy Tag objects left and right? This could be rather expensive as there are nested maps inside maps inside more maps. I was trying to figure it out but frankly I don't quite understand what they really want to do.

Comment: @n.m. Especially because the OP is at a learning stage, it would be extremely bad advice to use raw pointers. One non const container operation between pointer get and dereference and boom, undefined behaviour. All the nice life time issues added to his original problem. Which probably will have greater performance issues than copying some tags. If he does need the indirection trait of the pointer, his design is FUBAR. But hey lets teach a beginner bad style for the sake of

to quote Donald Knuth:"
premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming"

Comment: Raw pointers are not worse than raw references or iterators. All the same pitfalls apply. Iterator? Dereference and boom. Reference? Just boom, no need to do anything special. Given that OP plans to put a reference inside std::optional, they will have *all the semantics of raw pointers*, but this time with all the benefits of template metaprogramming and its associated compiler error messages. Did we need to wait until C++17 to go the full circle?

Comment: @n.m. I don't see where the OP plans to put a reference inside the optional. Which would be the mentioned FUBAR point, since then he should reorganise it anyway, like I suggested already in the answer. Otherwise you keep repeating yourself.

Comment: In one of the last comments under the main question.

Comment: @n.m. Yeah just found it, as you made my suspicious. Damn, tried to make him the architectural implications clear, like you already partly tried.